# Silex security configuration

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm struggling with silex security:

I have the following:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
```

and later on :

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/admin',
        'http' => true,
        'users' => array(
            // raw password is foo
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
        ),
    ),
);
```

but when i hit path "localhost/admin" Im getting:

```
Found error: No route found for "GET /admin"
```

cant understand the docs on page of silex rly.. Should I register security filters with controllers?

Idefined as follows function in controller:

```
public function admin(){
        return 'Hello';
    }
```

and route for this is:

```
$app->get('/admin', 'app.vendor_controller:admin');
```

now Im getting:

```
Hello
```

as soon as i hit path /admin , without authentication form. So there is no authentication proccess included...

EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

OK, so now after hitting url/admin I'm getting authentication banner with fields to put, as user and password, I'm typing admin , foo but there is no effect on this.

```
`A username and password are being requested by http://localhost:8080. The site says: “Secured”`
```

the code looks as follows:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'pattern' => '/admin',
        'http' => true,
        'users' => array(
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'foo')
        )));
$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
    array('/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
);

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
    'pattern' => '/admin',
    'http' => true,
    'users' => array(
        // raw password is foo
        'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'foo'),
    ))));
```

Comment: do you configured `security.access_rules` to allows only user with ROLE_ADMIN?

Comment: i belive i did not, how can I do this?

Comment: `'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'foo')`, the default encoder uses sha512, why did you set the plain-text password instead? did you change the `security.encoder.digest'`?

Comment: are you sure the default encoder is sha512?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configured a firewall that match every `/admin*` urls, but that don't mean that every URL requires authentication. You can be an [anonymous user](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html), and that would be fine. If you want tell silex that "the user need the `ROLE_ADMIN` to be allowed here", you need to add

```
$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
);
```

Comment: OK i found the solution, the given example at site wasnt Bcrypt decoded what is the default decoder for silex security atm.